# How to show line numbers on an XML file

Tags: xml

Say I have this XML file: https://prod-c2g.s3.amazonaws.com/db/Winter2013/files/courses-noID.xml

Is there a way to show the line numbers on the web page or do you have to copy to [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) to show the line numbers?

I want to avoid copying to Eclipse because then I cannot expand or minimize tags.

Comment: Your browser controls entirely how documents, or web pages, appear. Some browsers will certainly render stylesheet-less XML documents with individually-numbered lines.

Comment: thanks do you know of a browser that shows line numbers with xml documents?

Comment: If you view source in chrome, it will show line numbers (assuming your source XML file is separated into different lines).

Comment: "View page source" on Mozilla Firefox also displays the XML document, with numbered lins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One alternative is copying to another text editor, such as [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B), which has the ability of tag folding.

It is not ideal, but it is a solution that gives you line numbers and code folding.

Answer (score 0):

Check VSCode/VSCodium with your file:

```bash
wget https://prod-c2g.s3.amazonaws.com/db/Winter2013/files/courses-noID.xml
```

Looks like:

[image]